# creating a list of lists from text file where the new list is based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file that has lines in following order:

```
1 id:0  e1:"a"  e2:"b"
0 id:0  e1:"4"  e2:"c"
0 id:1  e1:"6"  e2:"d"
2 id:2  e1:"8"  e2:"f"
2 id:2  e1:"9"  e2:"f"
2 id:2  e1:"d"  e2:"k"
```

and I have to extract a list of lists containing elements (e1,e2) with id determining the index of the outer list and inner list following the order of the lines. So in the above case my output will be

```
[[("a","b"),("4","c")],[("6","d")],[("8","f"),("9","f"),("d","k")]]
```

The problem for me is that to know that the beginning of the new inner list, I need to check if the id value has changed. Each id does not have fixed number of elements. For example id:0 has 2, id:1 has 1 and id:2 has 3. Is there a efficient way to check this condition in next line while making the list?

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` for the job:

```
import itertools


def split_by(
        items,
        key=None,
        processing=None,
        container=list):
    for key_value, grouping in itertools.groupby(items, key):
        if processing:
            grouping = (processing(group) for group in grouping)
        if container:
            grouping = container(grouping)
        yield grouping
```

to be called as:

```
from operator import itemgetter


list(split_by(items, itemgetter(0), itemgetter(slice(1, None))))
```

---

The `items` can be easily generated from text above (assuming it is contained in the file `data.txt`):

```
def get_items():
    # with io.StringIO(text) as file_obj:  # to read from `text`
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:  # to read from `filename`
        for line in file_obj:
            if line.strip():
                vals = line.replace('"', '').split()
                yield tuple(val.split(':')[1]  for val in vals[1:])
```

Finally, to test all the pieces (where `open(filename, 'r')` in `get_items()` is replaced by `io.StringIO(text)`):

```
import io
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter


text = """
1 id:0  e1:"a"  e2:"b"
0 id:0  e1:"4"  e2:"c"
0 id:1  e1:"6"  e2:"d"
2 id:2  e1:"8"  e2:"f"
2 id:2  e1:"9"  e2:"f"
2 id:2  e1:"d"  e2:"k"
""".strip()


print(list(split_by(get_items(), itemgetter(0), itemgetter(slice(1, None)))))
# [[('a', 'b'), ('4', 'c')], [('6', 'd')], [('8', 'f'), ('9', 'f'), ('d', 'k')]]
```

This efficiently iterates through the input without unnecessary memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

## No other packages are required

---

## Load and parse the file:

- Beginning with a text file, formatted as shown in the question

```py
# parse text file into dict
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = [line[2:].replace('"', '').strip().split() for line in f.readlines()]  # clean each line and split it into a list
    text = [[v.split(':') for v in t] for t in text]  # split each value in the list into a list
    d =[{v[0]: v[1] for v in t} for t in text]  # convert liest to dicts
    
# text will appear as:
[[['id', '0'], ['e1', 'a'], ['e2', 'b']],
 [['id', '0'], ['e1', '4'], ['e2', 'c']],
 [['id', '1'], ['e1', '6'], ['e2', 'd']],
 [['id', '2'], ['e1', '8'], ['e2', 'f']],
 [['id', '2'], ['e1', '9'], ['e2', 'f']],
 [['id', '2'], ['e1', 'd'], ['e2', 'k']]]

# d appears as:
[{'id': '0', 'e1': 'a', 'e2': 'b'},
 {'id': '0', 'e1': '4', 'e2': 'c'},
 {'id': '1', 'e1': '6', 'e2': 'd'},
 {'id': '2', 'e1': '8', 'e2': 'f'},
 {'id': '2', 'e1': '9', 'e2': 'f'},
 {'id': '2', 'e1': 'd', 'e2': 'k'}]
```

### Parse the list of dicts to expected output

- Use [`.get`](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dgetltkeygt-ltdefaultgt) to determine if a key exists, and return some specified value, `None` in this case, if the key is nonexistent.
- [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) defaults to `None`, so this method never raises a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

  - If `None` is a value in the dictionary, then change the default value returned by `.get`.

    - `test.get(v[0], 'something here')`

```py
test = dict()
for r in d:
    v = list(r.values())
    if test.get(v[0]) == None:
        test[v[0]] = [tuple(v[1:])]
    else:
        test[v[0]].append(tuple(v[1:]))


# test dict appears as:
{'0': [('a', 'b'), ('4', 'c')],
 '1': [('6', 'd')],
 '2': [('8', 'f'), ('9', 'f'), ('d', 'k')]}

# final output
final = list(test.values())

[[('a', 'b'), ('4', 'c')], [('6', 'd')], [('8', 'f'), ('9', 'f'), ('d', 'k')]]
```

---

## Code Updated and reduced:

- In this case, `text` is a list of lists, and there's no need to convert it to dict `d`, as above.
- For each list `t` in `text`, index `[0]` is always the key, and index `[1:]` are the values.

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = [line[2:].replace('"', '').strip().split() for line in f.readlines()]  # clean each line and split it into a list
    text = [[v.split(':')[1] for v in t] for t in text]  # list of list of only value at index 1

# text appears as:
[['0', 'a', 'b'],
 ['0', '4', 'c'],
 ['1', '6', 'd'],
 ['2', '8', 'f'],
 ['2', '9', 'f'],
 ['2', 'd', 'k']]
    
test = dict()
for t in text:
    if test.get(t[0]) == None:
        test[t[0]] = [tuple(t[1:])]
    else:
        test[t[0]].append(tuple(t[1:]))
        
final = list(test.values())
```

---

### Using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

- Will save a few lines of code
- Using `text` as a list of lists from above

```py
from collections import defaultdict as dd

test = dd(list)
for t in text:
    test[t[0]].append(tuple(t[1:]))

final = list(test.values())
```